# KnockoutJS Mapping Plugin (observableArray)

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I am new to knockout and I am having a problem with using the mapping plugin as I do not understand how it maps my JSON data. 
This is a sample json data similar to what is in my program:

```
contact: {
        name : 'John',
        email : 'address@domain.com',
        phones : [{
            phoneType : 'Home Phone',
            phoneNumber: '999-888-777'},
            {
            phoneType : 'Business Phone',
            phoneNumber: '444-888-777'},
            }]
        }
```

As you can see, this json data contains an array of phones. 
I used knockout mapping plugin and I can bind the 'name', 'email' and loop the phone numbers in a 'foreach: phones' with no hassle until I try to make a ko.compute on the phoneNumber which is an object in the array phones.

```
@section scripts
{
    <script src="~/ViewModels/ContactModel.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var viewModel = new ContactModel(@Html.Raw(Model.ToJson()));
        $(document).ready(function () {
            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
        });
</script>

<label>Name</label><input data-bind="value: name" />
<label>Email</label><input data-bind="value: email" />
<label>Phones</label>
<table>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: phones">
     <tr>
      <td><strong data-bind='text: phoneType'></strong></td>
      <td><input data-bind='value: phoneNumber' /></td>
     </tr>
   /tbody>
 </table>
```

This is ContactModel.js

```
    var ContactModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);

    self.reformatPhoneNumber = ko.computed(function(){
    var newnumber;
    newnumber = '+(1)' + self.phones().phoneNumber;
    return newnumber;
    });

    };
```

For visual representation this is how this looks right now:

```
Name: John
Email: address@domain.com
Phones:
<--foreach: phones -->
Home Phone: 999-888-777
Business Phone: 444-888-777
```

What Im trying to do is to reformat the phoneNumber to display it this way:

```
Name: John
Email: address@domain.com
Phones:
<--foreach: phones -->
Home Phone: (+1)999-888-777
Business Phone: (+1)444-888-777
```

I try to do it by using the reformatPhoneNumber in place of phoneNumber in my binding like this:

```
<table>
      <tbody data-bind="foreach: phones">
         <tr>
          <td><strong data-bind='text: phoneType'></strong></td>
          <td><input data-bind='value: $root.reformatPhoneNumber' /></td>
         </tr>
       /tbody>
     </table>
```

But when I do, the value of reformatPhoneNumber doesn't appear.
I read somewhere here that I have to make the objects inside my observableArray also observable because ko.mapping doesn't do that by default. But I cannot picture how to do it as I was expecting ko.mapping plugin to do all the job automatically for me as I am new to this jslibrary. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much!!

Comment: Test question: What value does `self.phones().phoneNumber` refer to, exactly?

Comment: Also, what is `self` in your case? Please post a [minimal but complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). StackOverflow has the tools to include a runnable example right inside your question.

Comment: @Tomalak hi tomalak, thank you for your response, I editted my post to show my whole code as you requested. Thank you! Please show me the way to knocking my program out. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your use of naming (a computed named `reformatPhoneNumber`) suggests that you think of computeds as functions. While they are, technically, functions, they *represent* values. Treat them as values, just like you treat observables. In your case this means it should be called more like `formattedPhoneNumber` and should live as a property of the phone number, not as a property of the contact.

Separate your models into individual units that can bootstrap themselves from raw data.

The smallest unit of information in your model hierarchy is a phone number:

```
function PhoneNumber(data) {
    var self = this;

    self.phoneType = ko.observable();
    self.phoneNumber = ko.observable();
    self.formattedPhoneNumber = ko.pureComputed(function () {
        return '+(1) ' + ko.unwrap(self.phoneNumber);
    });

    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, PhoneNumber.mapping, self);
}
PhoneNumber.mapping = {};
```

Next in the hierarchy is a contact. It contains phone numbers.

```
function Contact(data) {
    var self = this;

    self.name = ko.observable();
    self.email = ko.observable();
    self.phones = ko.observableArray();

    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, Contact.mapping, self);
}
Contact.mapping = {
    phones: {
        create: function (options) {
            return new PhoneNumber(options.data);
        }
    }
};
```

Next is a contact list (or phone book), it contains contacts:

```
function PhoneBook(data) {
    var self = this;

    self.contacts = ko.observableArray();

    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, PhoneBook.mapping, self);
}
PhoneBook.mapping = {
    contacts: {
        create: function (options) {
            return new Contact(options.data);
        }
    }
};
```

Now you can create the entire object graph by instantiating a PhoneBook object:

```
var phoneBookData = {
    contacts: [{
        name: 'John',
        email: 'address@domain.com',
        phones: [{
            phoneType: 'Home Phone',
            phoneNumber: '999-888-777'
        }, {
            phoneType: 'Business Phone',
            phoneNumber: '444-888-777'
        }]
    }]
};
var phoneBook = new PhoneBook(phoneBookData);
```

Read through the [documentation of the mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html).

Expand the following code snippet to see it work.

```js
function PhoneBook(data) {
    var self = this;

    self.contacts = ko.observableArray();
    
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, PhoneBook.mapping, self);
}
PhoneBook.mapping = {
    contacts: {
        create: function (options) {
            return new Contact(options.data);
        }
    }
};
// ------------------------------------------------------------------

function Contact(data) {
    var self = this;
    
    self.name = ko.observable();
    self.email = ko.observable();
    self.phones = ko.observableArray();
    
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, Contact.mapping, self);
}
Contact.mapping = {
    phones: {
        create: function (options) {
            return new PhoneNumber(options.data);
        }
    }
};
// ------------------------------------------------------------------

function PhoneNumber(data) {
    var self = this;
    
    self.phoneType = ko.observable();
    self.phoneNumber = ko.observable();
    self.formattedPhoneNumber = ko.pureComputed(function () {
        return '+(1) ' + ko.unwrap(self.phoneNumber);
    });
    
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, PhoneNumber.mapping, self);
}
PhoneNumber.mapping = {};
// ------------------------------------------------------------------

var phoneBook = new PhoneBook({
    contacts: [{
        name: 'John',
        email: 'address@domain.com',
        phones: [{
            phoneType: 'Home Phone',
            phoneNumber: '999-888-777'
        }, {
            phoneType: 'Business Phone',
            phoneNumber: '444-888-777'
        }]
    }]
});

ko.applyBindings(phoneBook);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.js"></script>

<ul data-bind="foreach: contacts">
    <li>
        <div data-bind="text: name"></div>
        <div data-bind="text: email"></div>
        <ul data-bind="foreach: phones">
            <li>
                <span data-bind="text: phoneType"></span>:
                <span data-bind="text: formattedPhoneNumber"></span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

<hr />
Model data:
<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(ko.mapping.toJS($root), null, 2)"></pre>

Viewmodel data:
<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root, null, 2)"></pre>
```

Comment: Wow. You spotted right away how much knowledge I lack regarding Knockout that you go into full detail and explanation. Thank you so much man, you're a beast. Honestly I just jump right into it by copy-pasting examples into my program without reading the documentation. This helped me a lot Sir Tomalak, better than any jumpstart video I've watched so far. Thank you again!

Comment: Hi sir, I have a follow up question, what if for some reason, I need to access an object from a higher position in the hierarchy. For example I want to get the name from Contact viewModel and attach it to the formattedPhoneNumber in the PhoneNumber viewModel.

Comment: self.formattedPhoneNumber = ko.pureComputed(function () {
        return Contact().Name + ko.unwrap(self.phoneNumber);
    });

Comment: I assumed it should be something like this but it doesn't work

Comment: I would add that purely in the view. This works inside a `foreach` binding: `<span data-bind="text: phoneNumber"></span> (<span data-bind="text: $parent.name"></span>)`. The view knows how the bindings relate to each other (it knows the [*binding context*](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html)) and is the natural place to solve these kinds of display problems.

Comment: Yes sir ty I understand how that would work, but there's this other project of mine that requires some computation inside a child viewmodel that needs an object from a parent. Is this still possible?

Comment: I would be glad if you'd stop calling me "sir". That's really not necessary. Yes, that's still possible. Read through [this part of the documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html#customizing-object-construction-using-create) to the mapping plugin. Just pass the parent to the `PhoneNumber` constructor as an additional argument.

Comment: Sorry Tomalak I am still a student so it comes out of a habit maybe. Anyway, thank you again, I really appreciate your help. I guess I really need to go through that documentation tonight. Best regards from the Philippines.

Comment: Never mind, I'm just not used to it. -- The parent thing really is not far away from what I already gave you. Think about it some more, it will come to you.

Comment: inside function PhoneNumber(data) {} i try to subrscribe self.phoneNumber.subscribe(function(previousValue) {
console.log(previousValue)
}, self, "beforeChange");

but it doesnt work why?

Comment: @icinemagr Don't ask unrelated follow-up questions in the comments. Write a new question, include the code (read [mcve]), and demonstrate the problem.

Comment: i am doing it now and i will be glad if you help me i try 4 days now

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56053671/how-i-can-track-the-value-before-change-in-knockout-js here is my question