# beforeChange value is undefined in Knockout when using the mapping plugin

Tags: events, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

Based on the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29863531), I try to get the value before change in an observable with the following code.

```js
var phoneBook;

function debug(s) {
  $("#log").append('<br>' + s);
}

function PhoneNumber(data) {
  var self = this;
  self.phoneType = ko.observable();
  self.phoneNumber = ko.observable();


  self.phoneNumber.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    debug('newvalue: ' + newValue);
  });

  self.phoneNumber.subscribe(function(previousValue) {
    debug(previousValue);

  }, self, "beforeChange");

  ko.mapping.fromJS(data, PhoneNumber.mapping, self);
}
PhoneNumber.mapping = {};

function Contact(data) {
  var self = this;

  self.name = ko.observable();
  self.email = ko.observable();
  self.phones = ko.observableArray();

  ko.mapping.fromJS(data, Contact.mapping, self);
}
Contact.mapping = {
  phones: {
    create: function(options) {
      return new PhoneNumber(options.data);
    }
  }
};

function PhoneBook(data) {
  var self = this;

  self.contacts = ko.observableArray();

  ko.mapping.fromJS(data, PhoneBook.mapping, self);
}
PhoneBook.mapping = {
  contacts: {
    create: function(options) {
      return new Contact(options.data);
    }
  }
};

var phoneBookData = {
  contacts: [{
      name: 'John',
      email: 'address@domain.com',
      phones: [{
        phoneType: 'Home Phone',
        phoneNumber: '999-888-777'
      }, {
        phoneType: 'Business Phone',
        phoneNumber: '444-888-777'
      }]
    },
    {
      name: 'John2',
      email: '222address@domain.com',
      phones: [{
        phoneType: '22Home Phone',
        phoneNumber: '22999-888-777'
      }, {
        phoneType: '22Business Phone',
        phoneNumber: '444-888-777'
      }]
    }
  ]
};

var phoneBookDataOther = {
  contacts: [{
      name: 'peter',
      email: 'address@domain.com',
      phones: [{
        phoneType: 'Home Phone',
        phoneNumber: '999-888-777'
      }, {
        phoneType: 'Business Phone',
        phoneNumber: '444-888-777'
      }]
    },
    {
      name: 'almond',
      email: '222address@domain.com',
      phones: [{
        phoneType: '22Home Phone',
        phoneNumber: '22999-888-777'
      }, {
        phoneType: '22Business Phone',
        phoneNumber: '444-888-777'
      }]
    }
  ]
};

function dofunc() {
  ko.mapping.fromJS(phoneBookDataOther, phoneBook);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  phoneBook = new PhoneBook(phoneBookData);
  ko.applyBindings(phoneBook);

  setTimeout(dofunc, 5000)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.5.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.min.js"></script>

<ul data-bind="foreach: contacts">
  <li>
    <div data-bind="text: name"></div>
    <div data-bind="text: email"></div>
    <ul data-bind="foreach: phones">
      <li>
        <span data-bind="text: phoneType"></span>:
        <span data-bind="text: phoneNumber"></span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>


<div>
  <p id="log"></p>
</div>
```

The change event happens when the mapping plugin is called a again time (here after a timeout of 5 seconds), but the `previousValue` always comes out as `undefined`.

What i am doing wrong?

Here is the jsfiddle, too: https://jsfiddle.net/icinema/ungbz27s/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that you are using the mapping plugin wrong, and that your test data makes no sense.

There will only ever be a "previous" value, when you write a new value to *the exact same observable*. But the mapping plugin will throw away all your viewmodels and make new ones when you map a completely different set of data.

How is it supposed to know that the object with the name "John" in the first round is supposed to be the same person that has the name "peter" in the second round? It can't. So it throws out all the contacts including all their phone numbers and makes new ones. There never is a "previous" value in this scenario.

What you need is

- Give the contacts and phone numbers a key, so they can be identified as the same object across calls to `ko.mapping.fromJS`.
- Tell the mapping plugin which of the object's properties is supposed to be the key, by adding a `key` function to the mapping configuration.

Read the [documentation of the mapping plugin](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) - read the entire thing, it's not that much to begin with.

In the below example I used `name` as the key for contacts and `phoneType` as the key for phones, and I amended the test data so that they have the same names and phone types across both sets. You probably want to use a contact ID number as the key instead of the name.

The advantage of using the `key` function is that knockout will only update the phone number text in the DOM, instead of throwing out and recreating the whole `<li>` and everything in it, because it can recognize existing viewmodel instances and keep them. This will cut down on rendering time.

```js
/* global ko, $ */

function debug(s) {
  $("#log").append('<br>' + s);
}

function PhoneNumber(data) {
  var self = this;
  self.phoneType = ko.observable();
  self.phoneNumber = ko.observable();

  self.phoneNumber.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    debug('new value: ' + newValue);
  });

  self.phoneNumber.subscribe(function(previousValue) {
    debug('previous value: ' + previousValue);

  }, self, "beforeChange");

  ko.mapping.fromJS(data, PhoneNumber.mapping, self);
}
PhoneNumber.mapping = {};

function Contact(data) {
  var self = this;

  self.name = ko.observable();
  self.email = ko.observable();
  self.phones = ko.observableArray();

  ko.mapping.fromJS(data, Contact.mapping, self);
}
Contact.mapping = {
  phones: {
    create: function(options) {
      return new PhoneNumber(options.data);
    },
    key: function (data) {
      return ko.unwrap(data.phoneType);
    }
  }
};

function PhoneBook(data) {
  var self = this;

  self.contacts = ko.observableArray();

  ko.mapping.fromJS(data, PhoneBook.mapping, self);
}
PhoneBook.mapping = {
  contacts: {
    create: function(options) {
      return new Contact(options.data);
    },
    key: function (data) {
      return ko.unwrap(data.name);
    }
  }
};


var phoneBookData = {
  contacts: [{
      name: 'John',
      email: 'john@domain.com',
      phones: [{
        phoneType: 'Home Phone',
        phoneNumber: '999-888-777-old'
      }, {
        phoneType: 'Business Phone',
        phoneNumber: '444-888-777-old'
      }]
    },
    {
      name: 'Peter',
      email: 'peter@domain.com',
      phones: [{
        phoneType: 'Home Phone',
        phoneNumber: '22999-888-777-old'
      }, {
        phoneType: 'Business Phone',
        phoneNumber: '444-888-777-old'
      }]
    }
  ]
};

var phoneBookDataOther = {
  contacts: [{
      name: 'John',
      email: 'john@domain.com',
      phones: [{
        phoneType: 'Home Phone',
        phoneNumber: '999-888-777-new'
      }, {
        phoneType: 'Business Phone',
        phoneNumber: '444-888-777-new'
      }]
    },
    {
      name: 'Peter',
      email: 'peter@domain.com',
      phones: [{
        phoneType: 'Home Phone',
        phoneNumber: '22999-888-777-new'
      }, {
        phoneType: 'Business Phone',
        phoneNumber: '444-888-777-new'
      }]
    }
  ]
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  var phoneBook = new PhoneBook(phoneBookData);

  ko.applyBindings(phoneBook);

  debug('<hr>');
  setTimeout(function dofunc() {
    ko.mapping.fromJS(phoneBookDataOther, phoneBook);
  }, 3000);
});
```

```css
#log { font-family: monospace; font-size: small; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.5.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.min.js"></script>

<ul data-bind="foreach: contacts">
  <li>
    <div data-bind="text: name"></div>
    <div data-bind="text: email"></div>
    <ul data-bind="foreach: phones">
      <li>
        <span data-bind="text: phoneType"></span>:
        <span data-bind="text: phoneNumber"></span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

<hr>
<div id="log"></div>
```

Comment: i will edit my question in 1 second with a fiddle thank you for the answer and i will accept it in a minut if my fiddle works.

Comment: Ah, the context that you are actually using the mapping plugin was missing. See updated answer.

Comment: i have no words to thank you.The idea is to Pull the Json from server every 5 seconds.I just create a second object with name phoneBookOther so i can test .I did realize that the second object was different as i was waitting for your answer and i try to put a key for the name but no luck.Thank you again you save 4 days for me

Comment: That's exactly the situation where the `key` function can shine. Just be sure to pull *all* data from the server every time. The mapping plugin will throw out objects that are no longer in the input, so pulling only "diff" data from the server won't work.

Comment: how can i contact you .Are you a freelancer? i like to hire your services for 2 hours you dont need more :)

Comment: No, I'm not, sorry. :) I'm just a regular on Stack Overflow and answer questions when I see them and have the time.